# Add another ViewModelLocator convention in Prism (not override)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

The project (WPF) has these folders:

- Views
- ViewModels
- SubViews
- SubViewModels

How to get the Prism's `ViewModelLocator` working with them (Views> ViewModels & SubViews> SubViewModels), the solution I found only works with one convention:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

    ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) =>
    {
        var viewName = viewType.FullName.Replace(".ViewModels.", ".CustomNamespace.");
        var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
        var viewModelName = $"{viewName}ViewModel, {viewAssemblyName}";
        return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by checking the `viewType` and based on it, I return the appropriate ViewModel type:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

    ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) =>
    {
        string prefix;
        if (viewType.FullName.Contains(".SubViews."))
        {
            prefix = viewType.FullName.Replace(".SubViews.", ".SubViewModels.");
        }
        else
        {
            prefix = viewType.FullName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
        }
        var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
        var viewModelName = $"{prefix}ViewModel, {viewAssemblyName}";
        return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for registration of the pairs (not as bad as it sounds because you have to register for navigation anyway).

Alternatively, you implement both conventions one after the other - take the view's name, subtract "Views" and add "ViewModels" and try to get the view model's type. If that fails, subtract "SubViews" and add "SubViewModels" and try again. You could even check for cross combinations (e.g. "SubViews.ViewA" and "ViewModels.ViewAViewModel")...